# FACEBOOK API: Like Button

Tags: facebook

I am developping a Facebook application and the client has requested that the user has to have the possigbility to like different pages.

For example: Project, Inner Page 1 like button has to displayed the user has liked Project, Inner Page 1; Project, Inner Page 2 like button has to displayed the user has liked Project, Inner Page 2; and so on.

Is it possible? I think it is with  the ref attribute but could someone post me a simple example how to implement within an iframe application.

Comment: You cannot create Page likes via the API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/likes/#Creating

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can create a Like button for any page you want, you just need its URL.

You don't even need sample code, because Facebook provides a nice Like button generator: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Just copy the generated code and place it on your page / pages.